# Client Server Communication via REST API

Tags: ios, wcf, api, rest, role-manager

I am working in application have iOS native application as front end and c# .net as back-end. 
Currently I am using WCF REST API for any communication between iOS client and server.
In my application there hare two types of user "Administrator" and "Simple User". 
Application have some features those should enabled for admin user only and for "Simple User". 
I just need help to create application structure so I can easily maintain features as per end user role.
Also, feature are dynamics and will be added new features in future.

---

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with a new service, try switching to Web Api instead of WCF REST API as it is no longer supported by Microsoft.

http://www.asp.net/web-api

You could start using authorization module provided by Asp .Net. This is similar to what you use in an Asp .Net MVC application.